# What is an easy way to implement fprintf in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, file-io, ascii

In python, the following will let us write to `stdout`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("blah %d" % 5)
```

However, I want to be flexible about which stream we print to. I want to pass the stream as an argument into a function, as you would when calling `fprintf` in any of `C` derived languages. In the snippet of source code above, `stdout` is hard-coded into the write-statement. However, we want to be flexible about which stream we write to. we might want `stderr`, or some other stream instead of `stdout`.

Comment: `def something(stream): stream.write('blah %d' % 5); something(sys.stderr)` would work just fine; could you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: why do you need to pass `sys.stderr` or `sys.stdout` if both are accessible from everywhere?

Answer (score 3):

You say

> I want to pass the stream as an argument into a function

but that doesn't give you any extra flexibility. If you have a `some_stream` variable referring to the stream you want to write to, you can already do

```
some_stream.write("blah %d" % 5)
```

so you don't gain anything by making the stream a function argument. That said, the `print` function takes a `file` argument specifying what stream to write to:

```
print("blah %d" % 5, end='', file=some_stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do:

```
import sys
def fprintf(stream, format_spec, *args):
    stream.write(format_spec % args)
```

Here is an example of a call:

```
fprintf(sys.stdout, "bagel %d donut %f", 6, 3.1459)
```

Console output:

```
bagel 6 donut 3.145900
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `print` (Python) is a replacement for `printf` (C) and its derivatives (`fprintf`, `println`...). Here's how the above snippet would look like in Python:

```
import sys

print("blah %d" % 5, file=sys.stdout)
```

Or:

```
print("blah %d" % 5)
```

Comment: Actually, `print` has some nasty features: it prints a trailing `\n`, and prints spaces between arguments (the latter is unimportant here, but the former is).